# Different results running naive Bayes in Python sklearn vs. R bnlearn

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, naivebayes

**I tried naive bayes in both python and R and got different AUROC values. Why would that be the case?**

R Code:

```
library(bnlearn)
library(pROC)
library(tm)

corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(paste(data$TEXT, sep = ' ')))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control = list(tolower = TRUE,
                                  removeNumbers = FALSE,
                                  stopwords = TRUE,
                                  removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                  stemming = TRUE))
convert_codes <- function(x) { x <- ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0) }
dtm <- apply(dtm, MARGIN = 2,convert_codes) 
dtm <- as.data.frame(dtm)

model <- naive.bayes(dtm, approval, colnames(dtm)[-length(dtm)])


preds <- predict(model, dtm, prior = c(0.5, 0.5), prob = TRUE)
data$SCORE <- t(attr(preds, "prob"))[,2]
data$SCORE[is.nan(data$SCORE)] <- 0
print(auc(data$APPROVAL, data$SCORE))
```

**Result = 0.93**

Python Code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
    ('model', MultinomialNB())
])

pipe.fit(data["TEXT"], data["APPROVAL"])
preds = pipe.predict_proba(data["TEXT"])
print(roc_auc_score(data["APPROVAL"], preds[:,1]))
```

**Result = 0.76**

Why is there such a big discrepancy?

Comment: BTW, from the original title, one didn't know what you were asking about -- could have been about differences in speed, could have been about differences in code size, could have been asking how to port something from one to the other, etc. Please try to make sure a question title doesn't just describe the general topic you're asking about, but actually describes the *question itself* with enough specificity that someone else can get a sense of whether they have the same problem without needing to click through.

Comment: Sorry. I will try to go for longer more detailed titles.

Answer (score 0):

The pipelines you defined in R and Python are not the same:

- In R, the `weighting` parameter of `DocumentTermMatrix` defaults to `weightTf` and thus does not take the idf component into account.
- In Python, `TfidfVectorizer` has the default parameter `use_idf=True`, hence it uses the idf component.

Comment: I used CountVectorizer as well with Python and got similar results.